# ExpressJS not loading external javascript file mystery

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a basic site using expressjs. All of my static assets are being loaded correctly - html, css, images, icons, fonts... all except javascript files. This is a complete mystery to me as the script tag is rendered with working href link, but console network tab is showing all files except javascript. Check screenshots:

[image: Network Console]

[image: Script Tag]

I am setting the static assets correctly and have tried multiple variations to test all deliver the same result:

`app.use(express.static('public'));`

I suspect it has something to do with using **render** instead of **sendFile** but I could be mistaken.

`app.get('/', (req, res)=>{ res.render('index') })`

Anyone have any ideas to this mystery? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts must use src tag, not href. Change this in your script tag(s) and it should start working.

Comment: Thanks. So basic I missed it! Good eye, it's working now.